# Circuit with internal resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

> A circuit is formed by connecting a resistor between the terminals of a battery of electromotive force (emf) 6 V. The battery has internal resistance. Which statement is correct when 1 C of charge flows around the complete circuit?
>
> A. 6 V is the potential difference across the resistor.
> B. 6 J of thermal energy is dissipated in the battery.
> C. 6 J of chemical energy is transformed in the battery.
> D. 6 J of thermal energy is dissipated in the resistor.

I struggle to understand why A is wrong

Comment: The emf of the cell is the energy per unit charge shared between the internal and external resistances. The pds across these components add up to the emf.

Answer (score 0):

> I struggle to understand why A is wrong

Just draw electrical circuit and the answer will be obvious (see below). The battery voltage (emf) is divided to internal and external resistance. We do not know the exact ratio without additional data, but we do know that not all battery voltage will be across the external resistor.

The voltage you see on the battery terminals is lower than its open-circuit voltage by the voltage drop on its internal resistance

$$V_\text{term} = V_\text{oc} - I R_\text{int}$$

where $V_\text{oc}$ is the open-circuit voltage, $R_\text{int}$ is the internal voltage, and $I$ is the current. This is why you do not see full $6 \text{ V}$ voltage drop on the external resistor. For $I = 0$ the terminal voltage equals $V_\text{term} = V_\text{oc}$ and this corresponds to open-circuit conditions.

[image: schematic]